# Angular.js - How to access value of ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="PageController as page">
    <li ng-repeat="user in page.user_data.users">
     {{user.name}}
     <button ng-model="user.followed" ng-click="page.toggleFollow(user.id)">{{user.follow_text}}</button>
    </li>
</div>
```

How do I access or change the value of `user.followed` inside the function `toggleFollow`?

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app')
    .controller('PageController', ['$scope', UserService, PageController]);

    function PageController($scope, UserService){

        var me = this;
        me.user_data = [];           

        me.getUsers = function(){
           UserService.getUsers().then(function(data){
             me.user_data = data;
           });
        };

        me.toggleFollow = function(user_id){
         //how to get or modify the value of user.followed from here?

        };

    };
})();
```

Comment: Where is your user or your users inside of your controller?  And in Angular, there isn't a need to reference this, since you should actually be referencing your injected $scope

Comment: I'm getting the users data via a service, sec I'll update the code

Comment: Is that data ever injected into your controller?

Comment: Instead of passing `user.id` to `toggleFollow` function, just pass `user` itself, and inside `toggleFollow` you can directly access and change `user.followed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing in just the id of the user you follow, pass in the entire user object.

```
<button ng-model="user.followed" ng-click="page.toggleFollow(user)">{{user.follow_text}}</button>

me.toggleFollow = function(user){
    var followed = user.followed;
};
```